# Twilio: 3rd caller can barge in to a call in progress

Tags: javascript, php, twilio-php

I have a scenario where a Caller called an Agent. Caller and Agent are already engage. How can a 3rd caller(Supervisor) barge in to listen to their conversation.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply dial into the conference using TwiML like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>conference-room</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

you can use the muted attribute if you want the supervisor to hear the conversation, but not be heard:

```
muted="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to add a participant in an existing conference:

```
client.conferences(conferencesid)
    .participants
    .create({
        from: '{put your twilio number here}',
        to: `{put your supervisor number here}`,
        muted: true
    })
    .then(participant => console.log(partipant));
```